# Getting all input id from a form with JS

Tags: javascript

I created 2 functions : 
the first aims to build an HTML table based not on a JSON but on input of a search form. At this stage I just want to retrieve the information from the form and make a simple console.log

```
const showResultsHTML = resultRequest => {
    const pageFormElements = getAllFormElements(document.getElementById("requestForm"));

    console.log(pageFormElements);

}
```

My second function is browsing the form and extract the tag.id (input id, select id, etc.) from the form. 
While debugging the application or making a simple console.log tag value is fitting what i'm expecting.

```
const getAllFormElements = element => {
    Array.from(element.elements).filter(
        tag => {
            ["select", "textarea", "input"].includes(tag.id);
        }
    )
}
```

When I try to display the result in console in the showResultsHTML function, it returns undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning anything from the function returned by `getAllFormElements`.
The same problem exists in your filter - you're forgetting to `return`.

```
const getAllFormElements = element => {
    return Array.from(element.elements).filter(
        tag => {
            return ["select", "textarea", "input"].includes(tag.id);
        }
    )
}
```

or remove the curly braces for implicit return

```
const getAllFormElements = element => 
    Array.from(element.elements).filter(
        tag => ["select", "textarea", "input"].includes(tag.id)
    )
```

```js
const showResultsHTML = resultRequest => {

    const pageFormElements = getAllFormElements(document.getElementById("requestForm"));

    console.log(pageFormElements);
}


const getAllFormElements = element =>  Array.from(element.elements).filter(
        tag =>  ["select", "textarea", "input"].includes(tag.id)
    )


showResultsHTML();
```

```html
<form id="requestForm">
  <select id="select"></select>
  <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
  <input id="input">
</form>
```

Comment: I should have expect something stupid like this. Thanks ! it helps me... I still have to know why it returns empty array.

Comment: @davidvera see updated answer. You also forgot the return on the filter

Comment: It works fine. It seems i can't get the id so i select the tagName. I'll manage with it. It's perfect !

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) the `HTMLElement` Object has no `.elements` property or method, meaning the `getAllFormElements()` function doesn't returning anything.

Alternatively try [`parentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) to extract all the elements in an `HTMLElement` Object, like so...

```
const getAllFormElements = formElement => {
    return Array.from( formElement.children ).filter(
       tag => ["select", "textarea", "input"].includes(tag.id)
    ) 
};
```

Also, don't forget to return the result of the function process.

Hope that helped :)

---

See also:

- [Element API @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)
- [JavaScript Arrow Function Return Rules | Jake Trent](https://jaketrent.com/post/javascript-arrow-function-return-rules/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jamiec help i figure it out :

Here is my first function :

```
const getAllFormElements = element => Array.from(element.elements).filter(tag => ["select", "textarea", "input"].includes(tag.tagName.toLowerCase()));
```

Here is the second and how i can get the id :

```
const showResultsHTML = resultRequest => {
    const pageFormElements = getAllFormElements(document.getElementById("requestForm"));
    pageFormElements.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.id)
    });
}
```